# VB datagrid + array with custom class

Tags: vb.net, arrays, data-binding, datagridview

I have created a class "student" and made an array which contains students.
I would not only like to display the array in a datagridview, but the array should also be updated if the user makes changes to one of the students in the datagridview.

I succeeded in showing the array in the dgv: one way is using datasource prop, the other is doing is diagrammatically. However, i can't find out how to let the user edit the array by editing the dgv.

Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If the grid is not read only,and the data is bound from the datasource property,any value displayed should be editable if you double click it

Comment: the program starts with an empty (0 to 19) array. the datasource property for the dgv is the empty array. what i see when i run the program is an empty 5*20 table which is ok. but when i type some value in one of the cells and i want to move on to the next cell, the data in the first cell disappears

Comment: you can find (and edit) code i used here:
[LINK TO GOOGLE DRIVE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AEKirl5FaYDjISgE5jXpU9Co4deN1LTl8jcn9SuVKIs/edit)

Comment: These conditionsa should apply:                                      The EditMode property value is not EditProgrammatically.
The ReadOnly properties of the cell, row, column, and control are all set to false.,do they? check in the designer

Comment: i didnt change these props. if i would set editmode to programmatically, the user wouldnt be even able to type text in the datagrid.

Comment: i dont see any readonly props for cells, rows or columns...
editmode is ok and readonly for the dgv also ok

Comment: When you type in the data,try to hit return - and only then pass to the next cell - still erases the cells content?

Comment: i am not using any buttons or other things to control the datagrid. is that a problem you think? i just linked the array to the datagrid with the .datasource prop. when i enter text while the program is running and i press tab to go to the next cell, the text in the first cell disappears

Comment: enter moves the cursor to the underlying cell, erasing the content of the previous cell

Comment: hmm,i think that maybe the grid cant create an instance of the class for the row you are trying to edit, - try to add an empty,default constructor to the class,besides the one you wrote.

Comment: really strange... i now get an error in a totally other part of the program (loginpart) where i dont even use that class at all...

the error: The type initializer for 'Stage_manager.Module1' threw an exception. 

really no idea why that error is showing up :(

Comment: did you add the constructor to lln class?